# How can I get this menu to behave in IE6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

I have a site whose menu is functioning incorrectly in IE6, *and only IE6*.

A live preview of the site can be [seen here](http://www.wdmadvertising.com.au/preview/cfs/).

The HTML & CSS are too long to post here but please view the [source](http://www.wdmadvertising.com.au/preview/cfs/) and the [CSS](http://www.wdmadvertising.com.au/preview/cfs/c/cfs.css).

I have implemented conditional comments and the [IE6 Update jQuery plugin](http://ie6update.com/). Neither work.

Comment: Is there a MUST-HAVE reason why you would develop for IE6? Are your bosses/clients/users asking for it?

I ask because the sooner IE6 dies, the better the world for web designers will get. It's almost ten years old, and causes more problems with design/function/safety than its worth. Plus, Microsoft hasn't supported it for a while now.

Comment: By the way, your site looks excellent in Firefox 3.5.4, Safari 4, and Chrome 3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how relevant this still is, but in my experience multilevel menus are a pain to implement cross-browser. IE 6 generally needs some extra help in the form of a Javascript.

I've used the Suckerfish Dropdown method on many occasions, which [can be found here](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/). It uses unordered lists as well and provides IE6 support in the form of a Javascript. It might require rewriting your own menu logic, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try triggering `hasLayout` on any positioned object with css `zoom:1`.  Also, give explicit heights wherever posible.